Example of a sequentially continuous function that isn't continuous
Let $(X,\tau_1)$ and $(Y,\tau_2)$ be topological spaces and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function, that is, $f^{-1}(O)\in\tau_1$ for all $O\in\tau_2$.
If these topological spaces are metrizable, then we can treat them as metric spaces and the statement holds. Indeed, if, for all sequences $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ that converges to $x$, we have that $\lim f(x_n)=f(x)$, then $f$ is continuous.
In order to prove this fact, it is necessary to use some arguments that depend on distances, which means that the proof doesn't work for general topological spaces. Does anyone know of a counterexample for the statement?

Well, there is a notion of convergence in non-metric spaces.

Yes, there is: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Convergent_Sequence/Topology

Note that in an indiscrete space, every sequence converges to every point.

Oh I see. If $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ were the indiscrete topology, then every sequence converges to every point and we can't guarantee that the limit of $f(x_n)$ will be $f(x)$. Is this true?

I just noticed that your title question is the converse of the statement you make in paragraph 2.  Which one do you want?

Maybe the phrasing is not quite right. I'd like to show that: $\lim f(x_n)=f(x)$ for all sequence s.t. $x_n\rightarrow x$ does not imply continuity in general.

OK, so you want an example of a discontinuous function that still preserves all limits.

For example, let $f:(\omega_1+1)\to (\omega_1+1)$ be defined as $f(\alpha) = \alpha$ for $\alpha < \omega_1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Edit: The original answer I gave before is not a good example, so  I give another (Also thanks for the comment which kindly pointed out my  mistake):
Here is the new example:
Let $X=\mathbb R.$ Consider $X_1:=(X,\tau_1),\,X_2:=(X,\tau_2)$ with $\tau_1=$co-countable topology on $X$, and $\tau_2=$usual topology on $X$.
Let $f:X_1\to X_2,x\mapsto x$. Clearly $f$ is not continuous since $f^{-1}((0,1))=(0,1)\notin\tau_1.$
Now let $\{x_n\}\subset X_1$ be a sequence that converges to $x$.    Since $X_2$ is equipped with co-countable topology, the convergence of $x_n$ to $x$ implies $x_n$ is eventually a constant sequence $x$. (which converges to the unique limit $x$)
Thus $f(x_n)=x_n$ eventually becomes the constant $f(x)=x$ when $n$ large. In $X_2$, this is convergent so we proved $f$ is sequentially continuous.

I might be confused, but I don't buy your sequential continuity argument. Suppose $x=4$ and consider the constant sequence $x_n=7$. It converges to $x$ in $\tau_1$ but not in $\tau_2$ because it stays outside the cofinite neighborhood $\mathbb{N}\setminus{7}$ of $x$. This issue arises whenever the sequence repeats a value infinitely many times.

Thanks for the update! The new example works well. +1.

@JoonasIlmavirta You are correct, my answer at first is not sequentially continuous. I have editted to give another example, which may make more sense. Thank you!

No, there is not. Take an open subset $U$ of $f(x)$. Note that $V=f^{-1}(U)$ is an open subset of $x$. Choose $N$ large enough such that $x_n\in V$ for $n>N$. Then $f(x_n)\in U$ for $n>N$ and by definition $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$.

I think OP wants the converse:  preservation of limits of convergent sequences implies continuity.

Ok, I was confused... Because the title clearly states "Example of a continuous function between topological spaces where limf(xn) is not f(x)"

Yes, the title and body are definitely different.
